# Adapter modificado em tempo real

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma `Activity` chamada `ListaBasica` e um `Adapter` com o nome de `adapterBasico`. O `Adapter` contem uma lista de boletins. A `Activity` contem informações retiradas do `Adapter` como a soma do tempo informado no boletim.

Minha duvida é a seguinte: quando apago algum item do `Adapter` preciso que a `Activity` seja atualizada. Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de checar se o `Adapter` sofreu algum tipo de alteração, como acontece com o `EditText` quando se usa:

```
  EditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
    });
```

Tem algo nesse estilo para checar o `Adapter`?

Comment: Edumachdo acho que ninguém percebeu a sua pergunta. Você quer saber se existe um "adapter changed listener" ou qualquer coisa do gênero, certo? Se é isso, para que é que você quer isso? É que normalmente não é preciso nada disso, podes fazer esse tipo de coisas quando removes o item da Lista.

Comment: É exata mante isso que que estou procurando @JorgeB. Como eu disse antes eu preciso atualizar a soma dos tempos dos boletins, porem como estou deletando o item direto pelo Adapter, não consigo alterar a ListaBasica, por isso estou procurando pelo "adapter changed listener", caso não exista, encontrarei outra forma de efetuar a atualização.

Answer (score 1):

Após fazer a exclusão do item desejado, você deve adicionar a seguinte linha:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Você simplesmente pode remover o item desejado na lista usando o método `remove()` do seu `ArrayAdapter`. Onde uma maneira possível de fazer isso seria:

```
Objeto item = arrayAdapter.getItem([INDEX]);
arrayAdapter.remove(item);
```

Assim então a forma de modificar o `ArrayList` e chamar `notifyDataSetChanged()` no `ArrayAdapter`, que por desencargo de consciência, pode primeiro verificar se o `arrayAdapter` existe desta forma:

```
if(arrayAdapter!=null){
    arrayList.remove([INDEX]);
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```